# Matrix Chain Multiplication Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Assume that multiplying a matrix G1 of dimension p×q with another matrix G2 of dimension q×r requires pqr scalar multiplications. Computing the product of n matrices G1G2G3 ….. Gn can be done by parenthesizing in different ways. Define GiGi+1 as an explicitly computed pair for a given paranthesization if they are directly multiplied. For example, in the matrix multiplication chain G1G2G3G4G5G6 using parenthesization (G1(G2G3))(G4(G5G6)), G2G3 and G5G6 are only explicitly computed pairs.

Consider a matrix multiplication chain F1F2F3F4F5, where matrices F1,F2,F3,F4 and F5 are of dimensions 2×25,25×3,3×16,16×1 and 1×1000, respectively. In the parenthesization of F1F2F3F4F5 that minimizes the total number of scalar multiplications, the explicitly computed pairs is/are

F1F2 and F3F4 only

F2F3 only

F3F4 only

F2F3 and F4F5 only

=======================================================================

*My approach - I want to solve this under one minute, but the only way I know is that to use Bottom up Dynamic Approach by making a table and the other thing I can conclude is we should multiply with F5 at last because it has 1000 in it's dimension.So, please how to develop fast intuition for this kind of question!*

======================================================================

**Correct answer is F3F4**

Comment: The last case includes F2F2. What should it be?

Comment: @Paul Hankin It cant be F2F1, it cant be F2F4,it cant be F2F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to note is the dimension ***1×1000***. You better watch out for it if you want to minimize the multiplications. OK, now we do know what we are looking for is basically multiply a small number with ***1000***.

Carefully examining if we go with ***F4F5***, we would be multiplying ***16x1x1000***. But computing ***F3F4*** **first** , the result matrix has dimension ***3x1***. So going with ***F3F4*** we are able to get small numbers like **3,1** . So , no way im going with **F4F5**.

By similar logic I would not go with ***F2F3*** and loose the smaller 3 and get bigger **25** and **16** to be later used with **1000**.

**OK**, for ***F1F2***, you can quickly find that **(F1F2)(F3F4)** is not better than
**(F1(F2(F3F4)))** . So the answer is ***F3F4***